# S3 Delete Object policy on a directory

Tags: amazon-s3, policy

I have a bucket on which we have removed the DeleteObject privilege so that the Authenticated users don't delete the data.

The policy looks like this:

```
{
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Id": "test-s3-privileges",
"Statement": [
{
"Sid": "Stmt1",
"Effect": "Allow",
"Principal": {
"AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:root"
},
"Action": "s3:*",
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test/*"
},
{
"Sid": "Stmt2",
"Effect": "Deny",
"Principal": "*",
"Action": "s3:DeleteObject",
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test/*"
}
]
}
```

Now, I am testing HUNK (http://www.splunk.com/view/hunk/SP-CAAAH2E). This product wants to create a subdirectory called splunk under the "test" bucket and wants access to delete the objects it creates under the test/splunk/ directory.

So, I added the below statement to the policy:

```
{
"Sid": "Stmt3",
"Effect": "Allow",
"Principal": {
"AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:user/abc"
},
"Action": "s3:DeleteObject",
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test/splunk/*"
}
```

But I am still not able to delete data under test/splunk directory. Can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong? Or is there a better way to take care of this?

Note:- I want to delete data only from test/splunk/* and not from any other directories under test/*

Answer (score 1):

Explicit deny overrides any explicit Allows, as the default operation is Deny.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html

It is always better to explicitly allow just what you need instead of allowing "*" and denying specific actions. With explicit Allow actions you very rarely need to use explicit Deny statements.